# Virtual call in constructor

Tags: c++

```
class A{
  int i;
  public:
  A():i(0){cout<<" A : "<<i<<endl;}
  A(int a);
    virtual int val(){ return i+1; }

};

class B :public A{
 int i;
  public:
  B():A(),i(0){cout<<" B : "<<i<<endl;}
  B(int a):A(a),i(a) {
  }

  int val(){  return i;}
};

 A::A(int a):i(a){
   cout<<" A ; "<<i<<endl;
   A* ap = new B;
   cout<<" from A "<<ap->val()<<endl; ///expect 1 but got 0;
}

int main(){
  A a(5);
}
```

I expected the return val of call ap->val() to be 1, since I thought virtual mechanism doesn't work in constructor, but here I got value to be 0, since ap->val() resulted in call to B::val(). Why ?

Comment: A ; 5
 A : 0
 B : 0
 from A 0
This is out put of run

Comment: `ap->val()` is not called inside the construction of `val`

Comment: You're instantiating it with `new B`, so it's an instance of `B`, not `A`. When you call `val()`, it uses the actual type, not declared type.

Comment: Downvoting, as this is actually a poorly researched question.

Answer (score 2):

In this constructor

```
 A::A(int a):i(a){
   cout<<" A ; "<<i<<endl;
   A* ap = new B;
   cout<<" from A "<<ap->val()<<endl; ///expect 1 but got 0;
}
```

function call `ap->val()` is not applied to an object under construction.

In this statement

```
   A* ap = new B;
```

an object of type `B` was already created using its own constructor call and the function call is applied to the object of type B that was already created.

Comment: I understand this, so if object of B is successfully created in constructor of A, virtual call mechanism works even in constructor of A ?, I though in constructor it should default to local function call ?

Comment: @shanker861 If the function call would be applied to the object  under construction then you are right.

Comment: okay that make sense.